# Understanding why post is hidden

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

How do I make the answers to my questions posted earlier visible?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294451/using-rasterfromxyz-in-r-for-qgis-under-krige-baye?noredirect=1#comment472727_294451

Answer (score 8):

Your question was deleted by the "community" robot as it had no answers and had been downvoted.

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/roomba for more details of the process.

Answer (score 5):

That question was deleted by the Roomba seven months after it was asked and before anyone had volunteered their time to offer an answer to it.

To avoid this automated process I recommend continuing to edit any question you ask, both in response to any clarifications sought by potential answerers and to include any additional relevant information. That way it is better placed to either attract an answer, or an upvote, or both.